# Can I modify the #frame expression so it switches values slower?

Tags: node-editor, animation-nodes

I tried to add things like /2, /4 or so but it doesnt work like that.
I made a procedural water shader and thus want to get the constant movement, but it is too crazy with #frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the values :

Example: `#frame/100`

Comment: actually it doesn`t slow down visually

Comment: send a picture, showing the expression...

Comment: correction it worked in a similar node setup, just not with this one, so thank you

Comment: but used frame, not frames. Blender  showed warning saying frames isnt right

Comment: what? send the print! you don't need to show your entire shader. Only the specific node ... be voronoi, noise, wave etc ... and with the error

Comment: I cant get that error now but I swear it was! If I get it again soon, I`ll upload it

Comment: I can confirm there shouldn't be a `s`after `frame` in the expression